# dual variable of dual problem is a solution for primal problem in SDP?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, semidefinite-programming, qcqp

Hello I have a question on the dual variable in SDP problem

Actually, I'm reading the papers about QCR ( reformulating the 0-1 QCQP problem into a convex problem with tightest bound), but I will skip the detail and ask you the one that I haven't understood.

Here is a SDP problem (denote by (SDP) )

$$ max\ r \\
s.t $$

$$      \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        -r & \frac{1}{2}(c+u)^T \\
        \frac{1}{2}(c+u) & Q-diag(u) \\
        \end{matrix}
        \right] \ge 0
$$
$$
where \ r \in R \ \ \ u \in R^n $$

Then the (SDP) is a convex problem and satisfies Slater's condition.(take large negative r etc) Thus it has a strong duality property. The dual of (SDP) is as following(denote by (DSDP)

$$ min \ c^tx + Tr(QX) \\
s.t\ \ X_{ii} = x_i \ \ \ \ (1)\\
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & x^T \\
x & X \\
\end{matrix}
\right] \ge 0\\
where\ x \in R^n \ \ X \in R^{n*n}
$$
where Tr is a trace of matrix.

Here is my question. I understand the optimal value of (SDP) and (DSDP) are same due to the strong duality. However, many papers say that the optimal value of u in SDP are given by the optimal values of the dual variables associated with (1) in DSDP. Do you have an idea on why the optimal value of u in primal problem(SDP) can be obtained by dual variable of dual problem(DSDP)?

I heard the dual of dual problem is same with the primal problem in LP thus I take the dual problem of (DSDP), but it is not same with (SDP).

ref) Using a mixed integer quadratic programming solver for the unconstrained quadratic 0-1 program 
Improving the performance of standard solvers for quadratic 0-1 programs by a tight convex reformulation: The QCR method

Comment: The reason is that an optimal prima/dual pair is a saddle point of the Lagrangian. If you take the dual of (DSDP), you will obtain a problem that you can easily rewrite to (SDP).

Comment: Thanks, LinAlg I realized that dual of (DSDP) can be written in the form of (SDP). By the way, what does saddle point have to do with here?
I know saddle point of the Lagrangian is an optimal pt of primal and dual and has a strong duality (or conversely)... but what conclusion I can take from this?? what relation between the primal variable and dual variable of dual?